# Is it possible to have a static object and a static std::shared_ptr pointing to the same object?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Given the following class:

```
class Foo : public Base {
public:
  static const Foo FOO;
  static const std::shared_ptr<Foo> FOO_PTR;
  // .. virtual methods, etc
};
```

Is it possible to make it so that `FOO_PTR` points to `FOO`?

It seems hard since the usual way of creating a shared pointer is by taking ownership of a dynamically created pointer (e.g., via `new Foo{}`) or via `std::make_shared<Foo>()` both of which create a new object and don't really allow you to point the `shared_ptr` to `FOO`. Similarly, if I create the pointer first, it will have a different identity from `FOO` and so I think I am screwed here too.

A really dirty hack could be something like:

```
Foo Foo::FOO = Foo{};
std::shared_ptr<Foo> Foo::FOO_PTR = &Foo::FOO;  // dirty hack
Foo* dummy = new shared_ptr<Foo>(FOO_PTR);      // leaky, yuck
```

Basically we create the static `FOO` object first, then initialize the `shared_ptr<FOO>` with a pointer to that object. Now of course this object wasn't create via `new` so if the `shared_ptr` ever tries to delete it the world will probably end. To get around that the last thing we do is create another `shared_ptr` from the first, incrementing its reference count, and leak it, so the original `shared_ptr` will never try to delete its pointer.

Naturally, this makes me feel gross and I'm looking for a better solution.

Now an *obvious* solution would not be expose the `FOO` and/or `FOO_PTR` static objects in the first place but my hands are tied here and I cannot change that part of the design.

Comment: Why would you want the shared pointer to point to an object that wasn't dynamically allocated?

Comment: You would not use `shared_ptr` since the whole point is managing heap memory, which you don't have here.  You want `static const Foo* FOO_PTR;`

Comment: @juanchopanza - because the use of `shared_ptr` to hold objects of type Foo (and in particular many other types like Foo which share a common base class and `virtual` functions) is embedded in the API. Most of these objects are actually created and destroyed dynamically and the `shared_ptr` use is conventional, but there are also some singleton objects like `FOO` and `FOO_PTR` which are only created once but must place nice with the existing `shared_ptr` APIs.

Comment: @zzxyz - of course that's what I want in this simple example, but my hands are tied here in the actual use-case which is decidedly not simple. The use of `shared_ptr<Foo>` is widespread and embedded into the API and can't be changed without a huge effort and without breaking binary compatibility with an uncountable number of existing clients. This isn't a design question: the design is bad, I admit it. It's a pragmatic question on how to minimize the damage.

Comment: you could pass a custom, do-nothing deleter ... or use the ‘aliasing’ constructor to a dummy shared ptr ...

Comment: @BeeOnRope ahhh I see, apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it helps you with the API restrictions, but you could turn it around in that you create a shared_ptr-object dynamically and let `foo` be of type `Foo&` then:

```
class Foo {
public:
    static const Foo &FOO;
    static const std::shared_ptr<Foo> FOOPTR;
};

const std::shared_ptr<Foo> Foo::FOOPTR = make_shared<Foo>();
const Foo &Foo::FOO = *Foo::FOOPTR;

int main() {
    const Foo* f1 = Foo::FOOPTR.get();
    const Foo* f2 = &Foo::FOO;

    printf("%p == %p \n",(void*)f1,(void*)f2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually gets me half-way there: it's source compatible but will still break binary compatibility with existing clients (since references are a different type at the ABI level). It's a good half-step though. With some linker magic it may be possible to do a gradual transition.